# Editing layers in GeoServer with web application

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, geoserver, wfs, wfs-t

I wanted to edit layers in GeoServer where they are store in PostGIS database. I have refereed http://www.gistutor.com/openlayers/22-advanced-openlayers-tutorials/47-openlayers-wfs-t-using-a-geoserver-hosted-postgis-layer.html link for that, which works. But now i also wanted to edit previous feature and also add attributes of feature that has been added (note: from this link edited feature cannot be edited again once web application is refresh and attributes cannot be added) . I also wanted to correct edited mistake without entirely removing the feature. I also refereed links like [Ref Link 1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15878/geoserver-web-feature-service-wfs-in-open-layers-problem) and [Ref Link 2](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/getfeature-wfs.html). Please help me out for same. From this i wanted to create an web base application for editing layers from GeoServer . If any other opensource software if you can suggest for this web application please suggest. Please help me out for same.

Comment: You might want to accept some of the answers to your other questions. Otherwise, people might shun you and not help you.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE 2**

The link to the Community Edition of the OpenGeo Suite can be found [here](http://opengeo.org/products/suite/community/).

**UPDATE**

It would seem that OpenGeo has removed the community edition. You can still use [GeoExplorer](https://github.com/opengeo/GeoExplorer) though.

[image]

---

The [OpenGeo Suite Community edition](http://opengeo.org/technology/suite/download/linux/) has a GeoExplorer web app that you can use to style and edit layers. You can install it along with the OpenGeo Suite or by itself. The code is at [Github](https://github.com/opengeo/GeoExplorer).

Comment: Actually i wanted an Opensource software for same. Where OpenGeo suite paid.

Comment: The OpenGeo Suite has a community edition that is free.

Comment: I still have some dough. As you said community editor is free, can i publish my site on server after that? Can you please provide me link for community edition which is free.

Comment: Oh drat. It's gone now :( The links are dead. Will update my answer. GeoExplorer is still opensource though. You can download it from Github.

Comment: Just i visited link provided by you. Which provide this GeoExplorer which is trial version and need to pay. Actually i wanted opensource software. Please help me out.

Comment: Just updated my answer. It's on Github. You can get the source code.

Comment: sir can u tell me i have to download all files? and how to install that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5999/discussion-between-r-k-and-pari)